# How can I print the function description of an R package to Rmarkdown instead of terminal?

Tags: r

Using R markdown and trying to write a small document for the group I'm working in. I wanted to be able to print a functions description directly into the Rmarkdown document I'm writing. For example if I wanted the description for the function "cor" I would use

```
?cor
```

And this prints the description in the terminal I'm working on. Now using

```
print(?cor)
```

Or

```
dummy <- ?cor
print(dummy)
```

doesn't print the description to the Rmarkdown file, but instead again prints in inside the terminal and hangs, until the user exits at which point the RMarkdown pdf is generated. Unfortunately there is no sign of it within the pdf.

How can I make R print this to Rmardkdown and not the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the [printr](https://yihui.name/printr/) package. Make sure you install it before using the example Rmarkdown code below (i.e. run `install.packages('printr')` first), but here's an example of how to include a help file in an Rmarkdown created PDF:

````
---
title: "SO"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Printing Help

```{r}
library(printr)
help(sum)
```
````